# The timing of std::cout output is strange

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "1";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );

    std::cout << "2";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );

    std::cout << "3";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );

    return 1;
}
```

I want `std::cout` to be printed every second.

But when I run this code, the result value `123` is printed at the same time.

Why?

And please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: buffering, the output stream has a buffer, only writes when it fills or you ask it to with `std::flush` or `std::endl`. There is an option to turn this behaviour off, but it is beneficial to IO performance. In your case, add `std::flush(std::cout)` after your print statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cout` is buffered:

> C++11 27.4.2 [narrow.stream.objects]/3 : The object cout controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object stdout

so you need to explicitly flush this buffer to get what you want. Here are some ways to do this:

*1. Use `operator<<` with `std::flush`*

```
std::cout << "1" << std::flush;
```

*2. Use the free function `std::flush(std::basic_ostream)`*

```
std::cout << "1";
std::flush(std::cout);
```

*3. Use the member function `std::cout::flush()`*

```
std::cout << "1";
std::cout.flush();
```

*4. Use `operator<<` with `std::endl`*

```
std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
```

This will of course also insert a line-break and is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the standard stream after each **cout** otherwise they may wait till the end of the program to flush all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to buffering.
After each `cout`, you are required to flush the buffer, by using any of the statements like `std::flush(std::cout);`.

This may help you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::cout << "1";
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );
    std::flush(std::cout);

    std::cout << "2";
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );
    std::flush(std::cout);

    std::cout << "3";
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(1000) );
    std::flush(std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```